# How to add a bootstrap dropdown in a webix scheduler

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, webix

I am trying to add a dropdown in the week toolbar of webix's scheduler.

Looking over theyr documentation, I managed to add the Dropdown div in the toolbar, when I run the webpage the element that should show the dropdown appears, but when I click on it nothing happens(the dropdown elements don't appear).

This is how my week toolbar looks like:

```
  scheduler.config.week_toolbar = [

            { view: 'label', name: 'prevWeek', id: "prevWeek", width: 40, align: "center",
                label: "<div class='webix_cal_prev_button'></div>"
            },
            { view: 'label', id: "weekTitle", align: "center" },
            { view: 'label', id: "nextWeek", align: "center",
                label: "<div class='webix_cal_next_button'></div>", width: 40
            },
            {view: 'label', css: 'add', name: "multiB", id: 'multButton', label: "<div> <ul class='nav navbar-nav'> <li> <a href='#' data-toggle='dropdown'> DropDownMenu </a> <ul class='dropdown-menu'> <li><a href='#'>Item1</a></li><li><a href='#'>Item2</a></li> </ul> </li> </ul>" }      
        ];
```

I see no errors in console, and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.
Any advices would be appreciated!